# Assigning multiple results from CASE to WHERE col IN

Tags: sql-server, case

I get this message when using the case and i don't want to have an expression checking if the id is empty or not, that would be unnecessary extra code.

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

```
declare @idchar(2)
set @id= ''

select names from Units
where id in(    
    case @id
        when '' then (select id from Units)
        else @id
    end
)
```

Comment: Well, of course. You're using the subquery as an expression, which only allows you to have one result. What's your question, and what are you trying to do?

Comment: @Luaan i want the users to search for a specific id through a comboBox or to search for all(the case when id is ' ')

Comment: Yeah, you don't need a subquery for that at all :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can rewrite your query as follows:

```
select names from Units
where (@id = '' AND id in(select id from Units)) OR id = @id
```

In this case if `@id` is `''` then condition `id in(select id from Units)` is evaluated. If however `@id` has any other value, then condition `id = @id` is evaluated. This assumes that `@id` cannot have value `NULL`.

EDIT:
After looking at the query it seems that the query can be simplified a lot. You don't need `IN` part at all, because you are trying to access all records from the same table, so you can use even simpler query:

```
select names from Units
where @id = '' OR id = @id
```

Comment: I'd use parentheses to make sure it's obvious how the expression is evaluated (`(A and B) or C`).

Comment: @Luaan Yes, you're right - functionally it is the same but better readability always helps. I updated the answer

Comment: @dotnetom This truly works, but now i just have one doubt: is it recommended this way? or better i   have a separate store procedure that search for all the ids because the query is lenghty

Comment: @WeaponX After your question it seems you don't need to use the IN part, the simplified query will provide you the same result. I don't think having separate procedure to get all results will give you much performance benefit

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you never have to deal with nulls, this would do it:

```
SELECT names
 from Units
 where (id = @Id or (isnull(@Id, '') = ''))
```